# Nginx with worpress as sub-directory returning 404 in posts

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-404, permalinks

After adding various configurations into the Wordpress subdirectory, I can access without any issues the WP homepage, but I'm still not able to access the posts, returning 404.

> [www.test.com/blog](http://www.test.com/blog) - WP homepage, works perfectly fine

> [www.test.com/blog/test-post-for-blog](http://www.test.com/blog/test-post-for-blog) - WP Post, 404

Here is the config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name www.test.com;

  location ^~ /media {
    alias /var/local/test/static/media;
  }

  location ^~ /icons {
    alias /var/local/test/static/icons;
  }

  location /blog {
    alias /var/www/html;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    # try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_pass blog-test:9000;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
  }
}
```

And the log:

```
2022/02/09 14:47:25 [error] 32#32: *45 open() "/etc/nginx/html/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.10.10.10, server: www.test.com, request: "GET /blog/test-post-for-blog/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.test.com", referrer: "https://www.test.com/blog/"
10.10.10.10 - admin [09/Feb/2022:14:47:25 +0000] "GET /blog/test-post-for-blog/ HTTP/1.1" 404 187 "https://www.test.com/blog/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.87 Safari/537.36"
```

Checking the logs, it seems to look into the wrong place, which is ***/etc/nginx/html/index.php***, but if I add the alias in the php location block, then the homepage will stop working as well, which gets me a bit confused.

Currently, I'm not quite sure if the problem is the **alias** in the blog block ( nginx recommends not using *alias* together with *try_files*, apparently due to a bug ), or anything else. If it is indeed the alias directive, I'll try to add *root*, together with some rewrite rules to avoid modifying the file structure.

It really took me more than it should to figure it out, and still can not actually understand what might be the issue here.

**UPDATE 1 :**

This is extremely odd. With the following blog config, separating the php location from the blog, the WP posts are accesible, but not the homepage and admin, returning 404:

```
  location /blog {
    alias /var/www/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    alias /var/www/html;
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass blog-test:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

Now this works ( the blog and the posts can be accesed ) , but the admin seems to be going into a redirect loop:

```
  location /blog {
    alias /var/www/html;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    alias /var/www/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass blog-test:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
  }
```

**UPDATE 3 & FIX :**

This apparently works, but the config seems to be really unpleasant and unoptimised. If I try to nest the php location into the blog block, then the php files will download instead of rendering. If I try to use alias instead of root, some pages will not show resulting in 404. In any case, this seems to be functional:

```
  root /var/www/html; 
  index index.php;

  location /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog(.*)$ /$1 break;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
  }
          
  location ~ \.php$ {
    rewrite ^/blog(.*)$ $1 break;
    fastcgi_pass blog-test:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }
```

Comment: For my understanding: is your whole wordpress installation in the `blog` dir? Or are you trying to show the posts archive through a `blog` slug?

Comment: @JosFaber, yes, the /blog should point to the whole wordpress installation. The current nginx setup is also used to serve some static files, totally unrelated to the wordpress config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 3 & FIX :**

This apparently works, but the config seems to be really unpleasant and unoptimised. If I try to nest the php location into the blog block, then the php files will download instead of rendering. If I try to use alias instead of root, some pages will not show resulting in 404. In any case, this seems to be functional:

```
  root /var/www/html; 
  index index.php;

  location /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog(.*)$ /$1 break;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
  }
          
  location ~ \.php$ {
    rewrite ^/blog(.*)$ $1 break;
    fastcgi_pass blog-test:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Outside the /blog dir you might also have php files. There should be a separate block for the wordpress install that has the same settings, but then for the blog dir.

This could be the block for wordpress (tested in Docker)

```
  location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^/blog/(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass wp:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
  }
```

So your complete nginx config would look like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name www.test.com;
  root /var/www/html; 
  index index.php; 

  location ^~ /media {
    alias /var/local/test/static/media;
  }

  location ^~ /icons {
    alias /var/local/test/static/icons;
  }

  # This is for Wordpress
  location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^/blog/(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass wp:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
  }

  # This is for php files in the root. If there is no php to be parsed there you could leave these blocks out.
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
  
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass wp:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

UPDATE: I added a `root` and `index` property to the nginx server config.

Comment: The blog itself is the wordpress, so I dont actually need to have the separate configuration.

Comment: then you can leave those bottom location blocks out and you have your config with the correct settings for /blog

Comment: Yeah, but its almost the same thing, it wont fix the errors with the posts.

Comment: I've tested the answer it in a Docker environment, so there must be something else then. Did you set the WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME correctly?

Comment: And just to be sure, for this to work, the actual wordpress installation must be located in a `blog` dir in the docroot. So if nginx is set to serve from `/var/www/html` then wordpress should be installed in `/var/www/html/blog`.

Comment: I added a root property to the nginx config I had forgotten. That's a crucial thing

Comment: Thank you for your info.

I suppose WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME are set correctly, which are both to www.test.com/blog.

Regarding your info about having the wordpress installed in /var/www/html/blog, that it is not necessary, as I try to use "alias" instead of "root".

Comment: So, your goal is to have wordpress installed in the docroot of a webserver (e.g. `/var/www/html` and then serve it from `/blog`?

Comment: Exactly, which is already installed, and can be served at /blog, but the only thing not working are the blog posts, which return 404. I made some updates though, added them in the main post.

Comment: Then the alias should get you there. I would have to test that, but out of time for the moment.. Good luck